# Why is median not a sufficient statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, median, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose a random sample of $n$ variables from $N(\mu,1)$, $n$ odd. The sample median is $M=X_{(n+1)/2}$, the order statistic of the middle of the distribution.

How to prove that sample median is not a sufficient statistic of $\mu$? Do we need the probability density function of M?

I would like any help.

**Note 1**: I'm studying for the final exam of my course, and take previous exams to practice. This question appeared in a 2015 exam, that was given by other professor than mine, so it is possible that covers things that wasn't given by my professor. This question includes others two exercises:
(1) Is $M-\bar{X}$ an ancillary statistic for $\mu$?
(2) Prove that if $m$ is a unique point, such as $F_X(m)=1/2$, then $M \overset{p}{\rightarrow}m$.
I couldn't answer these two exercises, because ancillary statistics were not covered by my professor.

So, to see wheter $M$ is a sufficient statistic for $\mu$, I derived the probability density (pdf) function of $M$, that I bring below. But I think there is a more inteligent way to do, without getting the pdf first. So this is the reason I'm asking this question, to see if there is a better and faster way of solving this question.

**Note 2**: things I know about sufficient statistics:

$T$ is a sufficient statistic if $$ \frac{f_X(x|\theta)}{q(t|\theta)} $$ does not depend on $\theta$, where $f_X$ is the probability density function of $X$ and $q$ is the probability density function of $T$. Also, $T$ is a sufficient statistic if, and only if, there exist functions $g(t|\theta)$ and $h(x)$ such that $$f_X(x|\theta)=g(T(x)|\theta)h(x)$$ for all points of $\theta$

**Note 3**: The probability density function of M is

$$f_{M}(m)=\frac{n!}{\left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) ! \left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) !}[1-F_{X}(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}f_{X}(m)[F_X(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$

I divided the probability density functions of $(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $M$:
$$\frac{f_{X}(x|\mu)}{f_{M}(m)}=\frac{f_{X1}(x_{1}|\mu)\cdot ...\cdot f_{Xn}(x_{n}|\mu) }{\frac{n!}{\left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) ! \left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) !}[1-F_{X}(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}f_{X}(m)[F_X(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}$$

So we have (I don't know if is wright):
$$\frac{f_{X}(x|\mu)}{f_{M}(m)}=\frac{f_{X1}(x_{1}|\mu)\cdot ...\cdot f_{X_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}|\mu) }{\frac{n!}{\left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) ! \left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) !}[1-F_{X}(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}[F_X(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}$$
It seems that this expression depends of $\mu.$

Comment: 1. This appears to be a homework-like question; please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info . 2. What things do you know about sufficient statistics? e.g. definition/facts/results/theorems etc? 3. What have you tried in order to use the things you know to answer the question?

Comment: $T$ is a sufficient statistic if $$\frac{f_X(x|\theta)}{q(t|\theta)}$$ does not depend on $\theta$, where $f_X$ is the probability density function of $X$ and $q$ is the probability density function of $T$
Also, $T$ is a sufficient statistic if, and only if,  there exist functions $g(t|\theta)$ and $h(x)$ such that $$f_X(x|\theta)=g(T(x)|\theta)h(x)$$ for all points of $\theta$

Comment: That's definitely a good thing to know. Did you try to use it? However, is that the only thing you have? 4. You should consider how $M$ is related to the parameter of the distribution of the $X_i$, $\mu$. i.e.  note that $F$ and $f$ involve $\mu$

Comment: I'm not saying you *need* to use that fact, but if you just write it in terms of F and f without thinking about how those things relate to $\mu$ you may not even see that $\mu$ is present there and trick yourself into thinking it isn't.

Comment: I divided the probability density functions of $(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $M$:
$$\frac{f_{X}(x|\mu)}{f_{M}(m)}=\frac{f_{X1}(x_{1}|\mu)\cdot ...\cdot f_{Xn}(x_{n}|\mu) }{\frac{n!}{\left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) ! \left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) !}[1-F_{X}(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}f_{X}(m)[F_X(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}$$
So we have (I don't know if is wright):
$$\frac{f_{X}(x|\mu)}{f_{M}(m)}=\frac{f_{X1}(x_{1}|\mu)\cdot ...\cdot f_{X_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}|\mu) }{\frac{n!}{\left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) ! \left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) !}[1-F_{X}(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}[F_X(m)]^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}$$
that depends of $\mu$

Comment: Anyway, in this case, is it possible to know if M is a sufficient statistic without calculating its probability density function?

Comment: Sure, potentially, yes. One of those ways involves using a theorem you haven't mentioned, which is why I fished for additional knowledge.

Comment: What theorem? Might you share, please?

Comment: If it wasn't covered in your course it clearly wasn't intended that you use it; hence the question.

Comment: Further, you don't seem to have responded to the things that stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info would have you do (including being candid about the source of the question) leaving me more hesitant about the circumstances.

Comment: It might be useful to review some of the many questions on site on the topic of sufficiency.

Comment: @Glen_b I updated my question with more information that you ask for.

Comment: Rigorously speaking, showing $f(x|\mu)/f_M(m)$ does not depend on $\mu$ is not sufficient (check the factorization theorem more carefully).

Comment: Thanks, that all helps. To clarify; the theorem I was referring to was the Pitman–Koopman–Darmois theorem (which makes it very easy to establish), but I'm pretty sure you haven't covered it. You'll need to rely on the tools you do have, like the definition and the factorization theorem.

Comment: Look at some asymmetric distributions: The medians of $LN(0,1)$ and $LN(0,2)$ are both $1$, but their means are $\sqrt{e}$ and $e^2$. The medians of $B(1,\frac23)$ and $B(1,\frac34)$ are both $1$, but their means are $\frac23$ and $\frac34$. So obviously the medians don’t tell you everything about the means.

Answer (score 3):

A tricky part of this question is that the median sounds like a good estimator and mathematically it is not so clear what the mean is gonna improve.

So imagine the following simpler case:

- Say we have a sample of size $X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n$ where each $X_i$ follows (independently) a normal distribution $X_i \sim N(\theta,1)$ and we want to estimate $\theta$.
- We could make an estimate $\hat{\theta} = X_1$ and it is obvious that this is not a sufficient statistic. The other $n-1$ values can provide information about $\theta$ as well. The statistic $X_1$ is not sufficient.
- A sufficient statistic occurs when the distribution of the data is *independent* of the parameter $\theta$ conditional on the sufficient statistic. This is not true for $X_1$. For example, the distribution of $\bar{X}$ conditional on $X_1$ is not independent from $\theta$

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

One obvious way to check if a statistic is sufficient is to identify a minimal sufficient statistic (if it exists) and check if the minimal sufficient statistic is a function of your proposed statistic. Here we want to use the fact that a minimal sufficient statistic is a function of any sufficient statistic.

Take $n=3$ for example. A minimal sufficient statistic for $\mu$ is the sample mean $\overline x=\frac13(x_1+x_2+x_3)$. But $\overline x$ is not a function of the sample median $x_{(2)}$ only. You have to argue this formally.

In essence, sufficiency is concerned with data reduction (see [What does it mean that a statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient for a parameter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/84226/119261)). So $\overline x$ is sufficient means that all the information about $\mu$ in the sample can be condensed in $\overline x$. This happens to be the maximum possible data condensation in this model, which makes the sample mean minimal sufficient. Given $\overline x$, you can make inference on $\mu$. But knowing $x_{(2)}$ alone does not give you enough information about $\mu$. You also need to know $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(3)}$ to avoid any loss of information. A numerical example might help to make this point clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great technical question.  First I want to point out that your argument

> *$T$ is a sufficient statistic if $$ \frac{f_X(x|\theta)}{q(t|\theta)} $$ does not depend on $\theta$, where $f_X$ is the probability density function of $X$ and $q$ is the probability density function of $T$.*

does not hold. To see it, we know that for $T = \bar{X} \sim N(\mu, \frac{1}{n})$,  whence
\begin{align}
 & \frac{f_\mu(x_1, \ldots, x_n)}{q_\mu(t)} = 
\frac{(2\pi)^{-n/2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \mu)^2)}
{(2\pi n)^{-1/2}\exp(-\frac{n}{2}(t - \mu)^2)} = h(x)e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\bar{x} - t)\mu},
\end{align}
which depends on $\mu$ (you may argue that it does not depend on $\mu$ if substitute $\bar{x}$ to $t$, however, this is not what the proposed ratio formula says), but $\bar{X}$ is of course sufficient.  It looks like your "criterion" tries to match the definition of sufficiency of $T$ (Section 1.6, *Theory of Point Estimation*):

> *A statistic $T$ is said to be sufficient for $X$, or for the family $\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta, \theta \in \Omega\}$ of possible distributions of $X$, or for $\theta$, if the conditional distribution $X$ given $T = t$ is independent of $\theta$ for all $t$*.

A naive interpretation of the above definition is that the conditional density of the data $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ given $T = t$ is independent of $\theta$, which may be formally written as (note how the numerator in $(1)$ differs from that in your proposed ratio)
\begin{align}
f_{X|T; \theta}(x|t) = \frac{f_\theta(x, t)}{q_\theta(t)} \text{ is independent of $\theta$.} \tag{1}
\end{align}
However, a technical difficulty of the interpretation $(1)$ is that the "joint density" $f_\theta(x, t)$ of $(X, T)$ is degenerate (i.e., it is not a probability density on $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$.  In general, the conditional density defining relation $f_{X|Y = y}(x|y) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}$ only makes sense when $f(x, y)$ is a valid, non-degenerate density), hence $(1)$ is actually impossible to check.  For a relevant discussion, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778619/joint-density-of-a-random-variable-and-its-function).   To solve this difficulty, some 1-1 transformation between $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n - 1}, T)$ needs to be defined and the sufficiency needs to be augmented accordingly in terms of the conditional density of $Y$ given $T$.  For details, refer to Eq (1.17) -- Eq (1.19) in Section 1.9, *Testing Statistical Hypotheses*.

Having clarified this, one way to show that $M$ is not a sufficient statistic for $\mu$ is to find a subset $Y$ (possibly with transformation) of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, such that the conditional density of $Y$ given $T$ is well-defined (i.e., non-degenerate) and does depend on $\theta$. For simplicity and without losing of generality, assume $n = 3$.

One choice of $Y$ is $(X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}) = (\min(X_1, X_2, X_3), \max(X_1, X_2, X_3))$.  It is well known by the order statistic theory that the joint density of $(Y, M) = (X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}, X_{(2)})$ is
\begin{align}
f(x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}, x_{(2)}) = 6\varphi_\mu(x_{(1)})\varphi_\mu(x_{(2)})\varphi_\mu(x_{(3)}), \quad
x_{(1)} < x_{(2)} < x_{(3)}, \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\varphi_\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2}}$. And the marginal density of $X_{(2)}$ is (where $\Phi_\mu(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \varphi_\mu(t)dt$)
\begin{align}
f_{X_{(2)}}(x_{(2)}) = 6\Phi_\mu(x_{(2)})(1 - \Phi_\mu(x_{(2)}))\varphi_\mu(x_{(2)}). \tag{3}
\end{align}
$(2)$ and $(3)$ then give the conditional density of $(X_{(1)}, X_{(3)})$ given $X_{(2)}$ as
\begin{align}
f_{(X_{(1)}, X_{(3)})|X_{(2)} = x_{(2)}}(x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}|x_{(2)}) = 
\frac{\varphi_\mu(x_{(1)})\varphi_\mu(x_{(3)})}
{\Phi_\mu(x_{(2)})(1 - \Phi_\mu(x_{(2)}))},
\end{align}
which depends on $\mu$.

In contrast, you can verify that
\begin{align}
f_{(X_{(1)}, X_{(3)})|\bar{X} = \bar{x}}(x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}|\bar{x}) = 
\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}\exp\left(\frac{3}{2}\bar{x}^2 - 
\frac{1}{2}(x_{(1)}^2 + x_{(3)}^2 + (3\bar{x} - x_{(1)} - x_{(3)})^2)\right),
\end{align}
which is independent of $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $n = 2k+1$ is odd, and let $J_i$ be a ternary variable showing whether $X_i$ is equal to the median $M$, below it or above it. That is,
$$
J_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{$X_i > M$} \\
0 & \text{$X_i = M$} \\
-1 &  \text{$X_i < M$}
\end{cases}
$$
If $M$ is sufficient, then $(M,J_1,\dots,J_n)$ has to be sufficient as well. So it is enough to show that $(M,J_1,\dots,J_n)$ is not sufficient. What does sufficiency mean? That the distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ given $(M,J_1,\dots,J_n))$ is independent of the parameter, $\mu$ in this case. That this independence fails in this case is intuitive, but a bit cumbersome to write down.

With probability 1, exactly one of $J_1,\dots,J_n$ can be equal to 0, and the rest divided equally among +1 and -1 (since $N(\mu,1)$ is continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure the chance of seeing repeated values in a finite sequence of independent draws from it is zero.)
Without loss of generality, let us condition on
\begin{align}
A = \{M = m,\;\; J_1 = 0, \;\;&J_2 = +1, \dots, J_{k+1} = +1, \\ &J_{k+2} = -1, \dots, J_{2k+1} = -1\},
\end{align}
that is, $X_1$ is the median, the next $k$ observations are below the median and the next $k$ after are above the median.

Then, $X_1 = m$ is completely determined, and by independence $X_2,\dots,X_{k+1}$ are i.i.d. from $N(\mu,1)$ truncated to $(m,\infty)$ which we denote as $N(\mu,1; m, \infty)$. Similarly, $X_{k+2},\dots,X_{2k+1}$ are i.i.d. from $N(\mu,1)$ truncated to $(-\infty,m)$ which we denote as $N(\mu,1; -\infty, m)$. Clearly, the distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ given $A$ depends on $\mu$ and hence sufficiency fails.

If you want to write it down, technically,
$$
(X_1,\dots,X_n) \, |\, A  \;\;\sim \;\; \delta_{m} \otimes \Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^k N(\mu,1; m, \infty) \Bigr) \otimes \Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^k N(\mu,1; -\infty, m) \Bigr)
$$
where $\delta_m$ is the point mass measure at $m$, and $\otimes$  and $\prod$ denote products of measures. You can also consider other combinations of values for $\{J_i\}$ and it would be similar (you just get a different permutation of the same terms), but not necessary to establish the failure of sufficiency (one combination is enough).

You can also answer the question about ancillarity. A statistic is ancillary if its distribution does not depend on the parameter $\mu$.